Conditional criteria in a query formula
I'm writing a formula where information is pulled in from the named range SiteLevel. The formula should pull in the data based on the criteria in cell C2. I want to add in a condition that if C2 equals ALL, the criteria should be ignored and all rows be returned.

I've tried using query() and combining different WHERE and OR clauses with no luck.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please avoid sharing images of your spreadsheet data as the only source of data to avoid closure of the question. Instead, a public spreadsheet containing your sample data should be shared so that the community may replicate your issue easily. Make sure to add the expected input and output. Also, note that your email address can also be accessed by the public, if you share Google files.

Consider providing input and expected output as plain text table in the question. Click here to create a table easily, which are easy to copy/paste.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question useless for others or images, which are hard to copy. Also, note that your email address can also be accessed by the public, if you share Google files.

Use this filter() pattern:
=filter( 
  SheetX!A2:H, 
  (C2 = "ALL") + iferror(search(C2, SheetX!A2:A)), 
  (C3 = "") + iferror(search(C3, SheetX!E2:E))
)

The formula uses direct range references instead of the SiteLevel named range for clarity.
See filter(), search() and iferror().
